# Eclipse Juno - unable to attach Android API documentation archive file

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to attach Android API documentation Archive file (docs-15_r02.zip) in my Eclipse Juno as shown in the snapshot below (using **Project -> Properties**):

[image: Attaching the documentation]

The documentation page opens successfully form the archive file if I click **Open in Browser**.

When i click **OK** then following error is encountered:

> Error occurred while associating the source. See error log for more
>   details.

The archive documentation won't be attached, that is, documentation will be fetched from online source.
If I restart eclipse, following error message is displayed:

[image: After restarting the eclipse]

If i try to click, right click  or expand my eclipse project (java or android) following error message is displayed and I am not able to use the android projects. Now, I have to recreate eclipse workspace again to be able to use eclipse.

> An Internal error occurred during: "Initializing Java Tooling".
>   java.lang.NullPointerExcption

Note: I am using Android 4.0.3, API version 15. But, I am able to attach JAVA API documentation using similar technique. I tried this procedure many times cleaning my eclipse workspace but the same problem is replicated again and again.
Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the project in which u need this api... And copy the zip file into the Android Dependencies in project explorer. It may works...

Sorry if not.